# Spark structured streaming Kafka and triggerTime

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark structured streaming app reading Kafka source:

1. I write this stream with `triggerTime` option

   ```scala
   .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 seconds"))
   ```
2. but Spark read this source over 1 seconds

I know Spark automatically optimize batch time and batch size. So I think if I set `triggerTime` option 1 seconds, Spark shouldn't read Kafka source more than 1 second.
But it reads Kafka source over 1 second.

How can I explain this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In Spark Structured Streaming, the `trigger` function determines the processing time interval of the streaming query, i.e., the frequency at which the query will be run. The value that you pass to [`Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 seconds")`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/Trigger.html#ProcessingTime-long-) specifies that the query will be processed every second.

However, this doesn't mean that the batch size will be one second of data or that Spark will only read one second of data from Kafka each time. Instead, it means that every second, Spark will try to process whatever data is available in Kafka. The amount of data that Spark reads from Kafka each time is not controlled by the trigger time, but depends on other factors, such as Kafka's configuration and the rate at which data is being produced to Kafka.

Furthermore, the processing time doesn't guarantee that each batch will be processed within the given time. It's the interval at which Spark will check for new data and start processing it. If the processing of a batch takes longer than the specified time, then the next batch will be delayed until the current batch is done.

So, it's not that Spark is not respecting the trigger time, but that the trigger time does not control how much data Spark reads from Kafka each time. It only controls how often Spark checks for new data and starts processing it.

You can try and:

1. **Control the Rate of Data Input:**

   You can control the rate of data that Spark reads from Kafka by using the [`maxOffsetsPerTrigger` option](https://books.japila.pl/spark-structured-streaming-internals/kafka/options/#maxoffsetspertrigger). This option limits the number of records that your streaming query will read in each trigger.

   ```scala
   spark.readStream
       .format("kafka")
       .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
       .option("subscribe", "topic_name")
       .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "100") // Set your desired max offsets
       .load()
   ```

   This can help to prevent your query from being overwhelmed by a large amount of data. However, this is just a workaround and may not be the best solution if you need to process data in real-time and your processing time is long.
2. **Optimize Processing Time:**

   If your processing time is too long, you might need to optimize your query. This can involve many things, from tuning Spark configurations, optimizing your transformations, or scaling up your Spark cluster.

   An example of a [Spark configuration tuning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties) could be increasing the amount of memory allocated to each executor:

   ```scala
   val spark = SparkSession.builder
       .appName("SparkKafkaStreaming")
       .config("spark.executor.memory", "2g") // Increase as needed
       .getOrCreate()
   ```

   Without specifics about your query, it's hard to provide more detailed advice about optimization.
3. **Tune Kafka Configuration:**

   If the issue lies with the Kafka source, you might need to adjust the Kafka configuration. This can involve many things, from changing Kafka's batch size, to adjusting the rate at which data is produced to Kafka.

   For example, you might need to adjust the [`fetch.max.bytes`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#fetch-max-bytes) and [`max.partition.fetch.bytes`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#max-partition-fetch-bytes) properties on the Kafka consumer. These control the maximum amount of data per partition the server will return and the maximum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request respectively.

   You can set these properties when creating the Kafka source in Spark:

   ```scala
   spark.readStream
       .format("kafka")
       .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
       .option("subscribe", "topic_name")
       .option("fetch.max.bytes", "50000") // Set as needed
       .option("max.partition.fetch.bytes", "50000") // Set as needed
       .load()
   ```

Comment: I really appreciate for your answer. can i get the official document contain this contents "Instead, it means that every second, Spark will try to process whatever data is available in Kafka."

Comment: @lubiksss "official document"? I mean, this is my interpretation (in the context of your question) of the official Spark documentation of `Trigger.ProcessingTime()`